# Problems with Libertinus math fonts after upgrading TeX Live

Tags: fonts, spacing, texlive, letterspacing, libertinus

I have recently upgraded TeX Live (Mactex) from 2020 to 2022 and I am having some problems with the Libertine Math Fonts.

The pdf output below is what the two systems produce from the same source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Theorem.} \textit{Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$
 and $U$ a linear subspace. Then $\dim(U)\le\dim(V)$, with equality if and only if $U=V$.}
\end{document}
```

2020:
[image: TeX Live 2020]

2022:
[image: TeX Live 2022]

So the spacing around the "U" in the first line may not look perfect in either version, but it has become worse with the new one. Same for the "if U" in the second line. I am working on a book draft which is showing many such changes. (Some for the better, some for the worse.)

I have tried downgrading the libertinus and libertinust1math packages as well as some of the font files. No effect, so I do not even know which part of the installation is causing the change. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: write the author of the package.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I better try that then.

Comment: The problem is already in TeX Live 2021; the math letters lost their left sidebearing; coupled with the rather tight interword spacing, the effect is what you see.

Comment: @egreg Until it is fixed by the package author, do you know of anything a user can do to temporarily fix the sidebearings (perhaps with microtype or editing the font files)?

Answer (score 1):

The spacing has been significantly improved with [`libertinust1math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinust1math) v2.0.3 (2023-12-07).

[image: lib]