# Horizontal spacing in math mode with \mathbb

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-spacing

Why?

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scaled=.86]{FiraMono}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Looks good:
\begin{equation}
\vec{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{N}
\end{equation}

\noindent
Looks bad (too much space between R and N):
\begin{equation}
\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}
\end{equation}
Why?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/README, this has been repaired in NewTX 1.726. However, I don't see this version in TeX Live 2023 yet. Whoever has an influence on this, please feel free to nudge the TeX Live 2023 maintainers …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** The issue has been fixed in `newtx` v1.726 (2023-08-25)

---

It looks like a small design flaw (or choice?) in the blackboard bold fonts of `newtxmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\fboxsep-\fboxrule
\fbox{$\mathbb{C}$}
\fbox{$\mathbb{R}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually `\usepackage{newtxmath}` is enough to show the problem, which involves more than one letter: I'd say that at least A, K, X, and Z have the same issue, but that might be a matter of taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep-\fboxrule
\count255=65
\loop\ifnum\count255<91
\fbox{$\mathbb{\char\count255}$}
\advance\count255 by1
\repeat
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not much to do but inform the author.

Personally, instead of using `newtxmath` with the option `libertine` I use directly the `libertinust1math` font (both by the same author).

Comment: It must have been a relatively recent update, because in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599855/82917 there are no such spaces.

Comment: Just for the record, `libertinust1math` has its own issues: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/651204/208544

Comment: Thanks. By "inform the author", you mean write him to his email shown on CTAN? Or is there a better alternative that I am not aware of?

Comment: @17tmh Yes, Michael checks regularly his email. He might not answer right away but he is always reliable.

Comment: Okay, wrote an email. BTW I looked at `libertinust1math`, but somehow I am used to the `newtxmath` feel.

Comment: FYI: Read about linbertine/libertinus background and took another shot at `libertinust1math` ... now I think I will switch completely to libertinus/libertinust1math. Thanks again.

Comment: @campa It's not a design choice; it's a flaw. In the stock Debian-stable texlive, which got frozen in spring 2023, the spacing was also fine. The bug seems very recent, probably no more than half a year old. Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694211/newtxmath-superfluous-space-in-%e2%84%a4#comment1723013_694211 .