# Newtxmath: superfluous space in “ℤ)”

Tags: brackets, newtxmath, mathbb

Using TeX Live 2023 as of 2023-08-23 (also as of 2023-08-25), feeding `pdflatex` with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{newtxmath}% v1.723, 2023/07/30
\begin{document}%
The matrix multiplication (with the usual addition and multiplication on \(\mathbb{Z}\)) can be used \ldots.
\emph{The matrix multiplication (with the usual addition and multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}$) can be used \ldots.}% same issue in \emph{…} or with $…$.
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output]

The space between the double-struck Latin capital letter Z “ℤ” and the closing round paren “)” shouldn't be there.  Who is the culprit and what to do?  The maintainer of NewTX has been informed.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/693633/52406).

Comment: I confirm the problem. If I upgraded TeX-live from June 2023 to today's version August 2023, then the problem occurs. It means that in version June 2023 the ℤ was OK.

Comment: @mickep Yes, very likely.

Comment: According http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/README, this has been repaired in NewTX 1.726. However, I don't see this version in TeX Live 2023 yet. Whoever has an influence on this, please feel free to nudge the TeX Live 2023 maintainers …